# When doing sftp from windows server to linux server, junk characters like "��" are coming inside the file. How to prevent or remove these?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, sh, sftp

When doing sftp from windows server to linux server, junk characters like "��" are coming inside the file. How to prevent or remove these?

```
Problem: 

��01|I

Result Expected:

01|I
```

Comment: The file is likely encoded as `UTF-16` that Linux doesn't handle by default. (some Linux apps will, but your terminal isn't one)

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Converted the file to ASCII and it fixed the issue.

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t ASCII output.txt -o output.txt
```